# Do i need a License, for parsing a command/programm that is not written by myself?

Tags: licensing

// Example in c++:

```
string cmd1 = "sudo dmidecode";
string cmd2 = "sudo nethogs -t -s -a -d 1";
string cmd3 = "sudo intel_gpu_top -J";

FILE *pipe = popen(cmd1.c_str(), "r");
```

// Example in java:

```
String cmd1 = "sudo dmidecode";
String cmd2 = "sudo nethogs -t -s -a -d 1";
String cmd3 = "sudo intel_gpu_top -J";

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("bash","-c",cmd);
                
Process p=null;
if(debugThreadsLow) {System.out.println("execute: "+cmd);}
try {
    p = builder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();return null;}
```

My question is now: do i need to care about the license of dmidecode, intel_gpu_top or nethogs?

(Or include, for each program i parse, the license in my project?)

Comment: Yes, you need a license for using those programs. Assuming you have that (they're either free or GPL'ed or similar), what you need to do depends on how you intend to release _your_ software. What license do you intend to attach to your program?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the program you created? Do you want to convey it to others or is it only for private use / use within your organization?

Comment: @PMF I was thinking of gpl v3

Comment: @Phillipp 
I'm writing a program that collects information about the pc and displays it clearly. Things like cpu/gpu/disk usage, network I/O.
But specifically for the Linux desktop.
With the possibility to donate.

Comment: @PMF The GPL license specifically says that the output of licensed programs is also licensed only it it too is a covered work. I don't think that applies to the output of `dmidecode` and its siblings.

Comment: @doneal24 does this also apply to MIT Licensed programs?

Comment: It likely applies to almost all licenses. If you wrote a program to parse MS Word output you would not have to license it under the same Microsoft license. Discussed on [opensource SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same).

Comment: @doneal24 Ok, I thought this point was unclear in the GPL license (as I just had a similar question internally recently). Since the output of a GPL program may indeed contain stuff from the program (e.g. error messages, strings), this is not exactly the same as with a word document.

Comment: @PMF A word document has many strings from within word.exe along with embedded xml files. No creative content so certainly no copyright and unlikely covered by any reasonable license.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, that answers my question :).

Comment: @PMF If the output contains a significant part of the program itself, then you have to consider the license in the output. But this is usually only the case for certain programs like parser generators and compilers that reproduce significant parts of the code in the output executable.

Comment: @Brandin Makes sense. The compilers I know all have specific licenses just for this case, because, who wants to use a compiler that gives all (or significant) rights on the created software to the compiler vendor?